# Align images inside a li

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a list with images in. The list is a centered column in foundation.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/332msu1z/)

I need it so that the list elements images are all aligned in the same 'row' rather than going down the page.

How can I do this? I've tried:

```
li{
     display: inline;   
}
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Add `display: inline-flex` to your `ul`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="small-4 medium-6 small-centered columns">
    <li>
      <img src="http://api.ning.com/files/yallYWJbJ*ZVuc1yUMGYuXL4artVmJUl*Uuzcv2prT67gOy0nNVLPjrRE1GYTasJCNYmjgeSTgORbhuGbyRpcsaQbL1nvAPk/GreenSquare" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://api.ning.com/files/yallYWJbJ*ZVuc1yUMGYuXL4artVmJUl*Uuzcv2prT67gOy0nNVLPjrRE1GYTasJCNYmjgeSTgORbhuGbyRpcsaQbL1nvAPk/GreenSquare" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://api.ning.com/files/yallYWJbJ*ZVuc1yUMGYuXL4artVmJUl*Uuzcv2prT67gOy0nNVLPjrRE1GYTasJCNYmjgeSTgORbhuGbyRpcsaQbL1nvAPk/GreenSquare" />
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `ul`  and `li` a fixed size or % based width and use for lists a `display:inline-block`

```
#myUL{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
li{
    width: 32.5%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
}

img{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/332msu1z/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work, your fiddle aligns to the left, not center.

Comment: The fiddle does not align to the left, it is the because the ul has a full width and the lists a 100px each each, if you give them a percentage they will fill the container. but keep in mind you will need to check media queries for responsiveness

Comment: @panthro I have updated the demo, I think should work, the margins on the left and right are the row's margin, adding a column may fix that

Comment: Thanks but your update still doesnt adhere to the orignal question, it needs to be inside a small-centered div.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly - you need to remove "li" css being nested inside ul.
Then, having li width set to some certain size, and adding `display: inline-block;` to li's css should do the job.
It has greater universal browser support in opposition to inline-flex (if you're about to have a support for [IE9 and below](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)):

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="small-4 medium-6 small-centered columns">
        <li><img src="http://api.ning.com/files/yallYWJbJ*ZVuc1yUMGYuXL4artVmJUl*Uuzcv2prT67gOy0nNVLPjrRE1GYTasJCNYmjgeSTgORbhuGbyRpcsaQbL1nvAPk/GreenSquare"/></li>
         <li><img src="http://api.ning.com/files/yallYWJbJ*ZVuc1yUMGYuXL4artVmJUl*Uuzcv2prT67gOy0nNVLPjrRE1GYTasJCNYmjgeSTgORbhuGbyRpcsaQbL1nvAPk/GreenSquare"/></li>
         <li><img src="http://api.ning.com/files/yallYWJbJ*ZVuc1yUMGYuXL4artVmJUl*Uuzcv2prT67gOy0nNVLPjrRE1GYTasJCNYmjgeSTgORbhuGbyRpcsaQbL1nvAPk/GreenSquare"/></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none; 
}
li {
      display: inline-block;
      width:30%;
      margin-right: -4px;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/332msu1z/6/)

Comment: Thanks but this does not work, there are spaces between the elements

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that as requirement, so I don't see the reason to downvote. Also you might not have heard of this issue - https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ when dealing with inline-block elements. I've updated the answer - good luck buddy.